# MongoDb bulk insert limit issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im new with mongo and node. I was trying to upload a csv into the mongodb.

Steps include:

1. Reading the csv.
2. Converting it into JSON.
3. Pushing it to the mongodb.

I used 'csvtojson' module to convert csv to json and pushed it using code :

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test', function (err, db) { //connect to mongodb   
    var collection = db.collection('qr');
    collection.insert(jsonObj.csvRows, function (err, result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
    console.log("successfully connected to the database");
    //db.close();
});
```

This code is working fine with csv upto size 4mb; more than that its not working.

I tried to console the error

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
```

it returned `{}`

Note: Mine is 32 bit system.

Is it because there a document limit of 4mb for 32-bit systems?

I'm in a scenario where I can't restrict the size and no.of attributes in the csv file (ie., the code will be handling various kinds of csv files). So how to handle that? I there any modules available?

Comment: I think the `collection.insert` method requires the callback to be the 3th parameter, is your console.log's even being executed?

Comment: @MDG Its being executed. I'm getting result if its inserted. In scenario of not being insert is producing 'undefined' result

Comment: Ah, and this happens when you go over 4mb. I see.

Comment: Yes. My question is is there a workaround. if not how to find the maximum rows for different kinds of csv that we may handle.

Comment: Yes you will have to use streams, checkout this accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722891/inserting-large-csvs-into-mongodb-with-node-js-and-async-queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not having a problem on the parsing the csv into JSON, which presumably you are not, then perhaps just restrict the list size being passed to `insert`.

As I can see the `.csvRows` element is an array, so rather than send **all** of the elements at once, slice it up and batch the elements in the call to insert. It seems likely that the number of elements is the cause of the problem rather than the size. Splitting the array up into a few inserts rather than 1 should help.

Experiment with 500, then 1000 and so on until you find a happy medium.

Sort of coding it:

```
var batchSize = 500;
for (var i=0; i<jsonObj.csvRows.length; i += batchSize) {
    var docs = jsonObj.csvRows.slice(i, i+(batchSize -1));
    db.collection.insert( docs, function(err, result) {
        // Also don't JSON covert a *string*
        console.log(err);

        // Whatever
    }
}
```

And doing it in `chunks` like this.

Comment: It may be possible; but I was trying to find a size where I can insert maximum number of rows in a single insert. The issue is that the no of attribute in the csv also vary, so as the no of attribute increases the number of rows per size may reduce.

Comment: @SreekeshOkky Not sure your getting me. A little bit of a code block in the answer to clear that up.

Comment: Better practice is to use streams for this: https://gist.github.com/PaulMougel/8111810

Comment: @SreekeshOkky Or do as MDG just commented. The point of the answer is **break up** your parsed input into smaller chunks.

Comment: @MDG Yours is likely the better method of actual code. Was just trying to point out that the parsed documents needed to be broken up.

Answer (score 0):

You can make those data as an array of elements , and then simply use the MongoDB insert function, passing this array to the insert function